# How to implement FIND method of EF in Unit Test?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, unit-testing

I have a Web API 2.0 project that I am unit testing.  My controllers have a Unit of Work.  The Unit of Work contains numerous Repositories for various DbSets.  I have a Unity container in the Web API and I am using Moq in the test project.  Within the various repositories, I use the `Find` method of Entity Framework to locate an entity based on it's key.  Additionally, I am using Entity Framework 6.0.

Here is an very general example of the Unit of Work:

```
public class UnitOfWork
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;
    public IUnityContainer Container
    {
        get
        {
            return _container ?? UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
        }
    }

    private ApplicationDbContext _context;    
    public ApplicationDbContext Context
    {
        get { _context ?? Container.Resolve<ApplicationDbContext>();  }
    }

    private GenericRepository<ExampleModel> _exampleModelRepository;
    public GenericRepository<ExampleModel> ExampleModelRepository
    {
        get { _exampleModelRepository ?? 
            Container.Resolve<GenericRepository<ExampleModel>>(); }
    }

    //Numerous other repositories and some additional methods for saving
}
```

The problem I am running into is that I use the `Find` method for some of my LINQ queries in the repositories.  Based on this article, [MSDN: Testing with your own test doubles (EF6 onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314431.aspx#find), I have to create a `TestDbSet<ExampleModel>` to test the `Find` method.  I was thinking about customizing the code to something like this:

```
namespace TestingDemo 
{ 
    class TestDbSet : TestDbSet<TEntity> 
    { 
        public override TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues) 
        { 
            var id = (string)keyValues.Single(); 
            return this.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == id); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I figured I would have to customize my code so that `TEntity` is a type of some base class that has an Id property.  That's my theory, but I'm not sure this is the best way to handle this.

So I have two questions.  Is the approach listed above valid?  If not, what would be a better approach for overriding the `Find` method in the `DbSet` with the `SingleOrDefault` method?  Also, this approach only really works if their is only one primary key.  What if my model has a compound key of different types?  I would assume I would have to handle those individually. Okay, that was three questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on my comment earlier, I'll start with my proposed solution, and then explain why.

Your problem is this: your repositories have a dependency on `DbSet<T>`. You are unable to test your repositories effectively because they depend on `DbSet<T>.Find(int[])`, so you have decided to substitute your own variant of `DbSet<T>` called `TestDbSet<T>`. This is unnecessary; `DbSet<T>` implements `IDbSet<T>`. Using Moq, we can very cleanly create a stub implementation of this interface that returns a hard coded value.

```
class MyRepository
{
   public MyRepository(IDbSet<MyType> dbSet) 
   {
     this.dbSet = dbSet;
   }

   MyType FindEntity(int id)
   {
     return this.dbSet.Find(id);
   }
}
```

By switching the dependency from `DbSet<T>` to `IDbSet<T>`, the test now looks like this:

```
public void MyRepository_FindEntity_ReturnsExpectedEntity()
{
  var id = 5;
  var expectedEntity = new MyType();
  var dbSet = Mock.Of<IDbSet<MyType>>(set => set.Find(It.is<int>(id)) === expectedEntity));
  var repository = new MyRepository(dbSet);

  var result = repository.FindEntity(id);

  Assert.AreSame(expectedEntity, result);
}
```

There - a clean test that doesn't expose any implementation details or deal with nasty mocking of concrete classes and lets you substitute out your own version of `IDbSet<MyType>`.

On a side note, if you find yourself testing `DbContext` - don't. If you have to do that, your `DbContext` is too far up the stack and it will hurt if you ever try and move away from Entity Framework. Create an interface that exposes the functionality you need from `DbContext` and use that instead.

*Note*: I used Moq above. You can use any mocking framework, I just prefer Moq.

If your model has a compound key (or has the capability to have different types of keys), then things get a bit trickier. The way to solve that is to introduce your own interface. This interface should be consumed by your repositories, and the implementation should be an adapter to transform the key from your composite type into something that EF can deal with. You'd probably go with something like this:

```
interface IGenericDbSet<TKeyType, TObjectType>
{
  TObjectType Find(TKeyType keyType);
}
```

This would then translate under the hood in an implementation to something like:

```
class GenericDbSet<TKeyType,TObjectType> 
{        
  GenericDbSet(IDbSet<TObjectType> dbset)   
  {
    this.dbset = dbset;   
  }

  TObjectType Find(TKeyType key)   
  {
    // TODO: Convert key into something a regular dbset can understand
    return this.dbset(key);   
  } 
}
```

Comment: Actually, all the code I listed above is based on the MSDN article (outside of the Unit of Work, which is a generic representation.)  Also, unless I am wrong here, as far at the dependency the Repositories have on DbSet should be handled by the IoC container.  Also, IDbSet doesn't have a lot of async functions, so in my DbContext, I made all the DbSets virtual, and they are very testable.  The problem has to do with how the Find method works.  As stated in the article, it doesn't test well.  In my experience, it will always return null in a Unit Test.

Comment: That said, this is an interesting approach.

Comment: Also, I am not trying to test my DbContext.  I have a a TestContext, and I am loading fake data into the TestContext so I can run my Unit Test.

Comment: "Also, IDbSet doesn't have a lot of async functions, so in my DbContext, I made all the DbSets virtual, and they are very testable" - I personally do not think you should be testing against abstract classes, but interfaces. That's why I suggested this approach.

Comment: I hear you, but this is the recommended approach for EF6 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx#virtual. From the article - "Note that the DbSet properties on the context are marked as virtual. This will allow the mocking framework to derive from our context and overriding these properties with a mocked implementation."

Comment: Also, notice that the IDbSet does not have the same range of methods available compared to DbSet.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679233(v=vs.113).aspx  One key missing one is the Find and FindAsync.  Here is the DbSet https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset(v=vs.113).aspx.

Comment: I'm aware `IDbSet<T>` is missing some methods. In this case again I would prefer to not use `Find` in my architecture because it indicates I am coding against an implementation and not an interface (which I do not like). The note about mocking framework is true, but you're not using a mocking framework here :) I'm not really going to budge from my approach (obviously I'm bias) but if anyone else has better solutions I'm all ears! Alternatively you could get this code working and then ask something along these lines on Code Review who might be able to assist.

Comment: Dan, thank you for the feedback, and I did get the code to work using their implementation.  I just didn't like the way they were saying it should be implemented.  I was looking for a better solution.  I completely agree with using interfaces in as many cases as possible, but I couldn't with DbSet, since the Find method out performs all the other potential candidates.  In the end, I had to choose between performance and a flexibility, and I had to choose performance for this application.  Again, thank you for your answer.

Comment: You know what, IDbSet does have Find, but does not have FindAsync.  Thank you for smacking me into reality.  I am changing my DbSet to IDbSet and replacing all the FindAsync with Find.

Comment: I am not so sure that is wise! If you really, really want to use FindAsync, create a wrapper interface. `interface IAsyncDbSet<T> : IDbSet<T> { Task<T> FindAsync(int[] keys); }`. Then create a class like so: `class MyDbSet<T>: IAsyncDbSet<T> { public MyDbSet<T>(DbSet<T> set) { ... } }`. This enables you to still program against an interface (albeit one you write) with an extra wrapper class. You can then just delegate all of your actions to the injected DbSet.

Comment: You don't need to use a sledge hammer (replace every `Find` with `FindAsync`) when you can just use a normal screwdriver (create an adapter class + interface)

Answer (score 3):

I realise this is an old question, but after coming up against this issue myself when mocking data for unit tests I wrote this generic version of the 'Find' method that can be used in the TestDBSet implementation that is explained on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314431.aspx#find)

Using this method means you dont have to create concrete types for each of your DbSets. One point to note is that this implementaion works if your entities have primary keys in one of the following forms (im sure you could modify to suite other forms easily):

1. 'Id'
2. 'ID'
3. 'id'
4. classname +'id'
5. classname +'Id'
6. classname + 'ID'

   ```
   public override T Find(params object[] keyValues)
   {
       ParameterExpression _ParamExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "a");

       Expression _BodyExp = null;

       Expression _Prop = null;
       Expression _Cons = null;

       PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties();
       var typeName = typeof(T).Name.ToLower() + "id";
       var key = props.Where(p => (p.Name.ToLower().Equals("id")) || (p.Name.ToLower().Equals(typeName))).Single();


       _Prop = Expression.Property(_ParamExp, key.Name);
       _Cons = Expression.Constant(keyValues.Single(), key.PropertyType);

       _BodyExp = Expression.Equal(_Prop, _Cons);

       var _Lamba = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Boolean>>(_BodyExp, new ParameterExpression[] { _ParamExp });

       return this.SingleOrDefault(_Lamba);

   }
   ```

Also from a performance point of view its not going to be as quick as the recommended method, but for my purposes its fine.

Answer (score 0):

So based on the example, I did the following to be able to Unit Test my UnitOfWork.

1. Had to make sure my UnitOfWork was implementing IApplicationDbContext.  (Also, when I say UnitOfWork, my controller's UnitOfWork is of type IUnitOfWork.)
2. I left all of the DbSet's in my IApplicationDbContext alone.  I chose this pattern once I noticed IDbSet didn't include RemoveRange and FindAsync, which I use throughout my code.  Also, with EF6, the DbSet can be set to virtual and this was recommended in MSDN, so that made sense.
3. I followed the [Creating the in-memory test doubles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314431.aspx#doubles)
    example to create the TestDbContext and all the recommended classes (e.g. TestDbAsyncQueryProvider, TestDbAsyncEnumerable, TestDbAsyncEnumerator.)  Here is the code:

   public class TestContext : DbContext, IApplicationDbContext
   {
   public TestContext()
   {

   ```
        this.ExampleModels= new TestBaseClassDbSet<ExampleModel>();
        //New up the rest of the TestBaseClassDbSet that are need for testing
        //Created an internal method to load the data
        _loadDbSets();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<ExampleModel> ExampleModels{ get; set; }
    //....List of remaining DbSets

    //Local property to see if the save method was called
    public int SaveChangesCount { get; private set; }

    //Override the SaveChanges method for testing
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        this.SaveChangesCount++;
        return 1;
    }
    //...Override more of the DbContext methods (e.g. SaveChangesAsync)

    private void _loadDbSets()
    {
        _loadExampleModels();
    }

    private void _loadExampleModels()
    {
        //ExpectedGlobals is a static class of the expected models 
        //that should be returned for some calls (e.g. GetById)
        this.ExampleModels.Add(ExpectedGlobal.Expected_ExampleModel);
    }
   ```

   }

As I mentioned in my post, I needed to implement the FindAsync method, so I added a class called TestBaseClassDbSet, which is an alteration of the TestDbSet class in the example.  Here is the modification:

```
//BaseModel is a class that has a key called Id that is of type string
public class TestBaseClassDbSet<TEntity> : 
    DbSet<TEntity>
    , IQueryable, IEnumerable<TEntity>
    , IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>
    where TEntity : BaseModel
{
    //....copied all the code from the TestDbSet class that was provided

    //Added the missing functions
    public override TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        var id = (string)keyValues.Single();
        return this.SingleOrDefault(b => b.Id == id);
    }

    public override Task<TEntity> FindAsync(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        var id = (string)keyValues.Single();
        return this.SingleOrDefaultAsync(b => b.Id == id);
    }
}
```

4. Created an instance of TestContext and passed that into my Mock.

   var context = new TestContext();
   var userStore = new Mock<IUserStore>();

   //ExpectedGlobal contains a static variable call Expected_User
   //to be used as to populate the principle
   // when mocking the HttpRequestContext
   userStore
   .Setup(m => m.FindByIdAsync(ExpectedGlobal.Expected_User.Id))
   .Returns(Task.FromResult(ExpectedGlobal.Expected_User));

   var mockUserManager = new Mock(userStore.Object);

   var mockUnitOfWork =
   new Mock(mockUserManager.Object, context)
   { CallBase = false };

I then inject the mockUnitOfWork into the controller, and voila. This implementation seems to be working perfect. That said, based on some feeds I have read online, it will probably be scrutinized by some developers, but I hope some others find this to be useful.

Comment: again you are still coding against an implementation rather than an interface. :\ if it works it works but that is my gripe with this solution

Comment: @DanPantry - Again, this is coming from examples provided by MSDN.  I hear your gripe, but when I attempted to mock the context, it did not work properly.  I did forget to mention the dbset's are virtual. I have update the code.